# Query for multiple column with multiple values but in the different table with same column

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I know the title does not understand anything. But I would not know how to define it better.

I will explain more my problem.

I have 2 tables. A which in its interior has the following values:

Name table: battle

```
 res1 res2 winner
    225 552 552
```

In the second table I have:

Name table: fighters

```
ID  name
225 example 1
552 example 2
```

ID and res 1 res2 winner it is the same things.

How should I structure the table in such a way as to show, instead of the ID, the names?

Normally I always used the inner join, but I did not ever find myself more values to the same string.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have three aliases of table fighters for the desired output. Please see below query:

```
Select f1.name as Fighter-1, 
       f2.name as Fighter-2, 
       f3.name as Winner
From 
       battel b,
       fighters f1,
       fighters f2,
       fighters f3
Where
       b.res1 = f1.id AND
       b.res2 = f2.id AND
       b.winner = f3.id AND 
       (f1.id = 225 OR f2.id=225)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I would search a particular result? If I wanted to show only results where there example1?

Comment: you would need to add one more where clause with a condition where f1.id or f2.id is 225. Please check above post with updated query.

Answer (score 0):

You would multiple joins.  This is tricky for beginners because it requires table aliases:

```
select f1.name as name1, f2.name as name2, fw.name as winner
from battle b join
     fighters f1
     on b.res1 = f1.id join
     fighters f2
     on b.res2 = f2.id join
     fighters fw
     on b.winner = fw.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for three joins as the winner will always be one of the two opponents, so you simply need to do a CASE:

```
select f1.name as name1, f2.name as name2, 
   case when b.winner = b.res1 then f1.name else f1.name end as winner
from battle b 
join fighters f1
  on b.res1 = f1.id
join fighters f2
  on b.res2 = f2.id
```

To avoid any potential problems inserting or updating a winner who didn't play this game you might change the winner number to a simple flag (1 or 2) indicating who won:

```
res1 res2 winner
 225  552      2
```